# Update array of object in RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a simple app where a user can create a session, join that session and then create a username for that session. I'm currently having some trouble updating the "players" (users) when a new user joins the session.

My idea was to have a `session` observable that could detect changes, and then pass those changes to it's child components to show those changes in the UI:

app.component.html

```html
<app-join-session></app-join-session>
<ng-container *ngIf="session$ | async as session">
  <app-current-players [session]="session"></app-current-players>
  <app-new-user [session]="session"></app-new-user>
</ng-container>
```

session.service.ts

```js
export class SessionService {
  private subject = new ReplaySubject<Session>();
  public session$ = this.subject.asObservable();

  public setSession(session: Session) {
    this.subject.next(session)
  }

  public addUserToSession(session: Session): void {
    this.subject.next(session)
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
protected session$ = this.sessionService.session$;
```

new-user.component.ts

```js
public createUserName(userName: FormControl): void {
  this.apollo.mutate<CreateUser>({
    mutation: userOperations.CREATE_USER,
    variables: {
      name: userName.value,
      sessionId: this.session.id,
    }
  })
  .subscribe({
    next: ({data}) => {
      this.session.players.push(data!.createUser)
      this.sessionService.addUserToSession(this.session)
    },
    error: (e: GraphQLError) => {
      this.errorMessage = {...e}.message;
    }
  })
}
```

I thought maybe I could push the created user into the `players` session array and feed that to the `subject.next` so the observable would update.

But this doesn't work, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot add property 19, object is not extensible at Array.push ()

Is there a better/different way to update the `session` stream with a new player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an observable that contains an array you never want to mutate that array by pushing an object into the array, you want to always make the observable emit a new object. Your best friend in not mutating objects is the spread operator. I don't know why you are using a replay subject, use a behavior subject.

```
subject.next({ ...subject.value, players: [...subject.value.players, newPlayer] })
```

This will cause the observable to emit a new object with a new array of players.

The basis of Angular and one way data flow with observables is all about not mutating objects. It's a big topic but read up on how to not mutate objects and understanding the ... spread operator for arrays and objects is the key.

It is a new world and there is a lot to learn with reactive programming but learn to not mutate existing objects but instantiate new objects with the changes. There is way more to this topic than can be answered in a single stack overflow answer.

Comment: I'm using `replaySubject`  over `behaviourSubject` because the latter requires an argument, and I don't start the application with a session provided.

Comment: A ReplaySupject does take a parameter, it takes buffersize as a param. If you want a BehaviorSubject that starts without a value then use `new BehaviorSubject<Session | undefined>(undefined)`. A ReplaySubject with an empty buffer is not what you are looking for.

Comment: How do you update array of object by id ?

Comment: subject.next(subject.value.map(val => val.id = newValue.id ? newValue : val))